# Se pueden enviar notificaciones push usando unicamente Ionic y un servidor nodejs?

Tags: nodejs, ionic, ionic-framework

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación de ionic y quiero que reciva notificaciónes push, de esta aplicación ya tengo mi version de web la cual recive notificaciónes usando service work y nodejs, pero quiero implemntar esto para mi aplicación ioni y luego hacer el build para android, segun he visto, para mandara notificaciónes push se necesita firebase y yo quiero hacerlo sin utilizarlo unciamente con mi servidor nodejs que tengo montado, se puede hacer eso?

Comment: Si la app esta siendo ocupada (foreground) si se puede utilizando un socket,websocket o socket.io. Otra forma es con (local-notifications) https://capacitorjs.com/docs/apis/local-notifications. Pero ninguna de estas formas cumple exactamente lo mismo que las notificaciones push aunque tienen cierto parecido. Entre las opciones de terceros para notificaciones push que puede que no ocupen firebase esta OneSignal https://github.com/OneSignal/OneSignal-Cordova-SDK